# Optimizing nhibernate query

Tags: c#, nhibernate, session, optimization

I have the following relationship

```
    class Author
    {
       int Id;
    }

    class Publisher
    {
       int Id;
    }

    class Book
    {
       Publisher Publisher;
       Author Author;
       DateTime PublishDate;
    }
```

I'd like to optimize the following query:

```
    foreach (Publisher)
    {
       foreach (Author)
       {
          session.Query<Book>()
             .Where(x=> x.Author.Id == Author.Id && x.Publisher.Id ==Publisher.Id)
             .OrderByDescending(x=> x.PublishDate)
             .Take(5);
       }
    }
```

I realize that performance wise this code is horrible, how can I improve it and get the same results in fewer queries?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of ways we can do.It's Depend on your use case that which object you get first

Here i mentioned one way

```
DetachedCriteria forBook=DetachedCriteria.For<Book>();
forBook.CreateCriteria("Publisher");
forBook.CreateCriteria("Author");
ICriteria executableCriteria=forBook.GetExecutableCriteria(session);
executableCriteria.SetFirstResult(0).SetMaxResult(5);
executableCriteria.AddOrder(Order.Desc("PublishDate"));
executableCriteria.List<Book>();
```